# How to set the Origin to the center of an Array?

Tags: modifiers, origin

This sounds simple, but apparently it is not:
I want to rotate the resulting array by its center (without having to set the origin manually).

That's the original object:
[image]

And that's the resulting array:
[image]

How to set the origin to the center of this array?

Comment: I don't think you can without first applying the modifier. But after you do you can right click -> set origin -> origin to center

If you want to keep your array options open you can always have an empty at the center of the array and parent the array object to it to rotate.

Comment: The origin of the original object is still the origin of the whole thing. Without applying the modifier, you could create an empty at the point you need the new center and then add a copy rotation constraint that uses the empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an intuition that this MIGHT work, so try this. Hover your mouse(pointer) over where you want the origin to be(here:the centre of the array) and then hold down shift and right click .
This actually places the cursor(the small round thingy in the viewport) there. Now right-click the mesh and set origin to 3D cursor(there's an option for that under set origin).This places the origin where the 3D cursor is and voila! The origin is set to the centre of the mesh.
P.S. I'm a beginner in blender, like, an absolute noob. Please don't kill me if this doesn't work.

Comment: I'm on the wrong PC here to confirm this but I'd say your suggestion would work!

Comment: Sometimes, the simpler solution is the best solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My dirty solution was to create a cube that snapped to the corners of the array object, then move the 3d cursor to selection. With the 3d cursor at the right spot, I then selected the array object and set the origin to the 3d cursor.

There's probably a better solution here, I started using blender yesterday, literally.